# Javascript Regular Expression to fix toPrecision(2) output

Tags: javascript, regex

After going through num.toPrecision(2), you can get 123.45 rounding to a string 1.2e+2.

Best way I can see to fix this is:

```
num = 123.45;
num = num.toPrecision(2);

num = num.replace(/\.0e\+2/g, "00");
num = num.replace(/\.1e\+2/g, "10");
num = num.replace(/\.2e\+2/g, "20");
num = num.replace(/\.3e\+2/g, "30");
num = num.replace(/\.4e\+2/g, "40");
num = num.replace(/\.5e\+2/g, "50");
num = num.replace(/\.6e\+2/g, "60");
num = num.replace(/\.7e\+2/g, "70");
num = num.replace(/\.8e\+2/g, "80");
num = num.replace(/\.9e\+2/g, "90");
```

Output is 1.2e+2.  I need 120 (or 970 instead of 9.7e+2, etc.).

Is there a javascript regex expression with a don't care condition feeding to output.  Essentially do this in one instruction?

Comment: What if you try `num = num.replace(/\.(\d)e\+2/g, "$10")`?

Comment: Also you can try `num = Number(num.toPrecision(2))`

Comment: @Aguardientico That's what I was going to say but `var num = Number(Number(num).toFixed(2))`. But I don't understand what he's trying to do. @StainlessSteelRat can you add the output you expect?

Comment: Would not `num` be `12`? Why would any of those RegExp's work on `12`? Here's a basic list of `Math` Object properties: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_math.asp . Number Object properties: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp .

Comment: @Aguardientico That's what I needed.  Put it as answer and I award points.

Comment: An idiosyncrasy of toPrecision(2) (possibly toPrecision(1)) is to insert e+2 when rounding to 2 sig figs.  957 becomes 9.5e+2.  I want 950. My regex skills are poor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use regex, then you can change all regex for the following:

```
num = 123.45
num = num.toPrecision(2);    
num = num.replace(/\.(\d)e\+2/g, "$10") // "120"
```

If you prefer to keep `num` as number, then just transform the num again and then it will be fixed.

```
num = 123.45    
num = Number(num.toPrecision(2)) // 120
```

**EDIT**
To fix the case for `num.toPrecision(1)`

```
num = 123.45
num = num.toPrecision(1);    
num = num.replace(/(?:\.)?(\d)e\+2/g, "$10") // "10"
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just what I needed.  I want to keep it as a string to to avoid things like 120.000000000002

Comment: There's something about manipulating numbers with regexp that just doesn't seem right. Besides, this doesn't work. For `num.toPrecision(1)`, it returns `1e+2`.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, I agree completely, but javascript has always had this rounding issue.     Once a string, it is easy to process the exceptions (as demonstrated above).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the precision by dividing by a suitable exponent of 10, taking the floor, and remultiplying.

```
function change_precision(n, prec) {
  var num_digits = Math.floor(Math.log10(n));
  var new_digits = num_digits - prec;
  var multiplier = Math.pow(10, new_digits);
  return Math.floor(n / multiplier) * multiplier;
}

> change_precision(11111000, 2)
< 11000000

> change_precision(123.45, 4)
< 123.4
```